# Shell script to change digits with strings

Tags: linux, shell, sed, digits

I need to write a shell script using sed command to change digits with their words, for example 1->one, 2->two, ..., but when i got 2 digits ( 11, 25) do not change.

Any idea about this?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that, like me, you are running a version of `sed` which doesn't support regexp assertions, you could run `sed -rf myscript` with a script like this:

```
s/(^|[^[:digit:]])1($|[^[:digit:]])/\1one\2/g
s/(^|[^[:digit:]])2($|[^[:digit:]])/\1two\2/g
```

...continuing through the other digits. Breaking this down: `s` starts the substitute command. `/(^|[^[:digit:]])1($|[^[:digit:]])/` is the regular expression to replace. `(^|[^[:digit:]])` means capture either the beginning of the line or a character which isn't a digit. `1` is a literal 1. `($|[^[:digit:]])` means capture either the end of the line or a character which isn't a digit. `\1one\2` is the replacement string. `\1` adds the content of the first capture group. `one` adds a literal one. `\2` adds the second capture group. The `g` at the end indicates that the substitute operation should repeat as many times as possible on each line.

Comment: If this answer is useful to you, please accept it by clicking the green check mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any sample input and expected output so this may or may not do exactly what you want but it is the right general approach:

```
$ cat tst.awk         
BEGIN {
    split("one two three four five six seven eight nine",dig2wrd)
    dig2wrd[0] = "zero"
}
{
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
        $i = ($i in dig2wrd ? dig2wrd[$i] : $i)
    print
}

$ cat file            
a b 1 c 22 d
3 e 11 4 5 6

$ awk -f tst.awk file
a b one c 22 d
three e 11 four five six
```